# Navigate through different query strings without javascript resetting references to old variables

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extract data from [this](http://www2.ashfield.gov.uk/cfusion/Planning/plan_arc_results2_v_date.cfm?fromyear=1974&frommonth=01&fromday=01&to_year=2017&to_month=06&to_day=26&StartRow=39427) website. I've written a function which extracts the data I need in javascript:

```
const total_planning_applications = 39437
const min_value = 39407
var superArray = []
var i = 1
window.location.href = "http://www2.ashfield.gov.uk/cfusion/Planning/plan_arc_results2_v_date.cfm?fromyear=1974&frommonth=01&fromday=01&to_year=2017&to_month=06&to_day=26&StartRow=" + (total_planning_applications - i*10)
window.onload = loop

//main loop handler to be called when window.onload event. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload  for details.
function loop(){
    concatTables(superArray,document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0],function(){
        i++
        if(min_value < (total_planning_applications - i*10)){
            window.location.href = "http://www2.ashfield.gov.uk/cfusion/Planning/plan_arc_results2_v_date.cfm?fromyear=1974&frommonth=01&fromday=01&to_year=2017&to_month=06&to_day=26&StartRow=" + (total_planning_applications - i*10)
            window.onload = loop            
        }
    })
}

//merges a table from the Ashfield council's website with the mainArray (disincluding headers)
function concatTables(mainArray,table,callback){
    if(mainArray=[]){
        mainArray.push(["RefNum","RefLink","Application","Location","Proposal","ADCDecision","ValidDate","Map","MapLink"])
    }
    arr = getArray(table)
    arr.shift()
    mainArray.push(arr)
}


//gets an array from the table on the Ashfield counsil's website
function getArray(table){
    var ret = []
    for(var i=0;i<table.children.length;i++){
        var row = table.children[i]
        var aRow = []
        var bSkip = false
        for(var j=0;j<row.children.length;j++){
            if (row.children.length==1){
                bSkip = true
                break;
            }
            aRow.push(row.children[j].innerText.trim().replace(/\r|\n/g," "))
            if(row.children[j].getElementsByTagName("a")[0]!=undefined){
                aRow.push(row.children[j].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href)
            }
        }
        if(!bSkip){
            ret.push(aRow)
        } else {
            bSkip = false
        }
    }
    return ret
}
```

However when I try to execute the javascript from the console, the javascript stops executing after the first loop. I realise that this occurs due to security reasons and that browsers disallow cross-website javascript.

However, in this case I don't necessarily have to navigate to another site. Rather I need to navigate to a certain query string. Is it possible to navigate to a query string without losing the javascript runtime?

If not are there any other solutions other than using something akin to [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/)?

Comment: I guess the other possible solution would be using HTTP request.

Comment: Provably a good usecase for serverside scripting...

Comment: I do need to learn a good serverside language... I would use NodeJS but I don't have access to that here... IT Policy is very strict... :/

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was the following:

**Why navigate to the website at all?**

Instead use HTTP Requests:

```
var total_planning_applications = 39437
var min_value = 30000
var base_ref = "http://www2.ashfield.gov.uk/cfusion/Planning/plan_arc_results2_v_date.cfm?fromyear=1974&frommonth=01&fromday=01&to_year=2017&to_month=06&to_day=26&StartRow="
window.mainArray = []
var i = 1
//debugger;
httpGetAsync(base_ref + (total_planning_applications - i*10),loop)

//main loop handler to be called when window.onload event. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload  for details.
function loop(docx){
    concatTables(window,docx.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0],function(){
        i++
        console.log(`Processing...(${i})`)
        if(min_value < (total_planning_applications - i*10)){
            httpGetAsync(base_ref + (total_planning_applications - i*10),loop)      
        } else {
            console.log("All done!")
            console.log(JSON.stringify(window.mainArray))
        }
    })
}

//merges a table from the Ashfield council's website with the mainArray (disincluding headers)
function concatTables(window,table,callback){
    if(window.mainArray.length==0){
        window.mainArray.push(["RefNum","RefLink","Application","Location","Proposal","ADCDecision","ValidDate","Map","MapLink"])
    }
    arr = getArray(table)
    arr.shift()
    window.mainArray = window.mainArray.concat(arr)
    callback()
}


//gets an array from the table on the Ashfield counsil's website
function getArray(table){
    var ret = []
    for(var i=0;i<table.children.length;i++){
        var row = table.children[i]
        var aRow = []
        var bSkip = false
        for(var j=0;j<row.children.length;j++){
            if (row.children.length==1){
                bSkip = true
                break;
            }
            aRow.push(row.children[j].innerText.trim().replace(/\r|\n/g," "))
            if(row.children[j].getElementsByTagName("a")[0]!=undefined){
                aRow.push(row.children[j].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href)
            }
        }
        if(!bSkip){
            ret.push(aRow)
        } else {
            bSkip = false
        }
    }
    return ret
}

function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
            parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(this.responseText,"text/html")
            callback(xmlDoc);
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(); //null
}
```

The main difference here is we work only on the xml document returned by `httpGetAsync()` function. It also has the added benefit of working silently and not disrupting the user! In this case I didn't want to generate too much traffic so I called the function recursively, however it should also be possible to have many asynchronous calls in parallel, which should also be possible with this technique.